# Problems with String[]

Tags: java

I have a String[] LinesFromFile which contains about 100 lines loaded from a file e.g.

> LinesFromFile[0] is "Line1"
>
> LinesFromFile[1] is "Line2"
>
> LinesFromFile[2] is "Line3"
>
> ...
>
> LinesFromFile[99] is "Line100"

I want to now create a new String[] SomeLinesFromFile and assign this variable some of the lines from LinesFromFile.

I would have thought it would have been as simple as:

```
String[] SomeLinesFromFile = null;
int offset = 45;

for (i = 0; i < 10, i++)
{
    SomeLinesFromFile[i] = LinesFromFile[offset + i];
}
```

I would have assumed this code would set SomeLinesFromFile[0] to SomeLinesFromFile[9] with the values of LinesFromFile[46] through to LinesFromFile[56].

When I try running this on my android device it crashes. What am I missing here?

Comment: You can't assign a value to `null[i]`; you need to instantiate an array to store into.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
String[] SomeLinesFromFile = null;
```

`SomeLinesFromFile` is `null`, so you cannot then do:

```
SomeLinesFromFile[i] = ...
```

You need to create an array first, e.g.:

```
String[] SomeLinesFromFile = new String[10];
```

---

*Incidentally, it is considered bad practice to name your variables starting with capital letters.  So you should always use `someLinesFromFile` instead of `SomeLinesForFile`.*

Comment: I knew it was something trivial :-(

Answer (score 1):

Your second array is null, initialize it with the right dimension (10 should be enough in your case) :

```
String[] SomeLinesFromFile = new String[10];
int offset = 45;

for (i = 0; i < 10, i++)
{
    SomeLinesFromFile[i] = LinesFromFile[offset + i];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Change this:

```
String[] SomeLinesFromFile = null;
```

to this:

```
String[] SomeLinesFromFile = new String[10];
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use ArrayList instead to avoid a fixed size.

http://www.java-tips.org/java-se-tips/java.lang/use-of-arraylist-class.html

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to initialize the string array:

```
String[] SomeLinesFromFile = new String[10];
```

Answer (score 1):

SomeLinesFromFile[i] doesn't exist.  SomeLinesFromFile is set to null.  You could try something like this:

```
String[] SomeLinesFromFile = new String[0];
String[] Temp = null;

int offset = 45;

for (i = 0; i < 10, i++)
{
    Temp = new String[SomeLinesFromFile.length +1];

    if(SomeLinesFromFile.length>0){
        System.arraycopy(SomeLinesFromFile, 0, Temp, 0, SomeLinesFromFile.length;
    }

    Temp[i] = LinesFromFile[offset+i];
    SomeLinesFromFile = new String[Temp.length];
    System.arraycopy(Temp, 0, SomeLinesFromFile, 0, Temp.length);
}
```

That's a bit of a rough sketch up, so there might be something I missed, but that's the gist of it.  There may be a better or easier way to do it, but that's what I can come up with.  Here's the doc on [arraycopy](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/System.html#arraycopy%28java.lang.Object,%20int,%20java.lang.Object,%20int,%20int%29) if you need it.  Basically, you have a temp array that pulls down the new information.  It then stores it in the other array to allow a new temp array to be created to pull more information in.

Comment: Hardly.  First of all, it's not that complicated at all.  Second, it's more useful code.  By the time I saw the question, the obvious answer had already been given about 7 times.  Initialize the array to 10 elements.  My code would work if there were 10 elements, or 1000.  The less dependant your code is on little details, the more likely it will work when you change it.  If, in this example, he changed the range from 10 to 11, he'd be hunting down an OutOfBounds exception with any other code snippet in this question.  Thought I'd give a (still easy) example that was more robust.

Comment: Holo Dev you are correct. Though the obvious answer was adequate for what I needed your method is superiour and programmers should always work towards making their code more robust.

Answer (score 0):

`SomeLinesFromFile` is `null` (which you probably can see in the logs).
I suggest using a List such as a LinkedList or ArrayList instead by the way. They can be converted to an array as well when you are done using the method `toArray()`